# How do I ReSeed a database table with my data every time I run my app?

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a web-app that uses EF5. I have two tables that are my main concern. I have a members table and a claims table. I have false members that I need for testing purposes and this saves their claims to the claims table.

There is real data in these tables as well that I do not want to change. Some of the false members are missing different data or need specific things to process said claim. How do repopulate my false members exactly as I want them without dropping the database.

I have looked into Code First Migrations on www.pluralsight.com but I am not sure how to tell it to always seed the 10 false members and remove the new claims from the claims table. Some of the members have past claims so I only wanna remove the ones that get added during testing.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with migrations. Migrations seeds data only when your migration is executed = when something changes in your class structure and database needs to be modified as well. You just need to call your initialization logic from `Application_Start` but you should make it conditionally complied - I guess such code should not get into production version.

Comment: No. That is nothing special - what part of the answer isn't clear?

Comment: I am a junior developer and I haven't actually touched the global.asx file. My senior guy generally handles that. I was hoping for a tutorial on what editing the Application_Start method would do

Comment: `Application_Start` is method called every time your web application restarts - it is usually used for application global initialization code. You should probably consult with your senior developer if it is good idea to have initialization logic for tests in your application directly.